# An interchangeable substitute to RxJava in the domain layer

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, coroutine, clean-architecture

A lot of articles and open source projects out there prefer making usecases return an Observable or one of it's variants, I currently go for that too, but I have doubts.
Although, I see the benefits of this in unit testing as the RxJava2 testing api is definitely rich, I suspect this is best way to go.

What if I wanted to refactor and use Coroutines instead for the sake of an example?.
The above approach will undoubtedly require changes in both domain and presentation layers (changes in both the affected area and the one using it).

On the other side, making usecases receive lambda params or callbacks in any shape, makes the presentation layer unaware of what the usecase is using to execute it's logic, but the thing is, with this approach I'll have to figure out how to test the usecases myself.

Is there an approach I'm not seeing that unties use cases from this burden?

Comment: *makes the presentation layer unaware of what the usecase is using to execute it's logic* - isn't that a good thing?

Comment: @TimCastelijns of course it is, my concern is about unit testing when using the callback approach.

Comment: You should pick one approach and stick to it, if you use MVVM, it actually makes sense to use `Observable` in the ViewModels and the Views and not Callbacks

Comment: @OmarMainegra architectural patterns like MVVM have nothing to do with rxjava etc

Comment: @TimCastelijns I didn't say so, I said `Observable`, and in his concrete case RxJava's `Observable` does make a lot of sense in MVVM

Comment: @TimCastelijns, It could be `LiveData` as well, which BTW are `Observable`s too

Comment: @OmarMainegra I'm aware of what you're suggesting, my problem still stands, having the domain layer not Rx specific, or at least preventing exposure of such streams.

Comment: But why want to prevent that, it looks like over-engineering, there is nothing wrong on using RxJava in your ViewModels

Comment: @OmarMainegra you're looking at it the MVVM way, I'm ok with using Rx or LiveData or even ObservableFields in the presentation layer (ViewModel), the issue is that I don't want the ViewModel to know what the usecase is using to execute, so that the logic inside of it can be changed without changing anything in presentation, callbacks solve that, but it's not quite the best approach when it comes to unit testing.

Comment: @AhmedAshrafGamal Like I said before, IMHO that's over-engineering, I don't see anything wrong in that, actually the opposite, what you can't expose is the implementation details (i.e. using a `Subject` instead of an `Observable`)